# Does JdbcCursorItemReader have to close connection?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

There is an example from Spring Batch document (https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#cursorBasedItemReaders)

```
public ItemReader<RevertedBillCredit> verifyCreditReader() {     
        JdbcCursorItemReader itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader();
        itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        itemReader.setSql("SELECT ID, NAME, CREDIT from CUSTOMER");
        itemReader.setRowMapper(new CustomerCreditRowMapper());
        int counter = 0;
        ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
        itemReader.open(executionContext);
        Object customerCredit = new Object();
        while(customerCredit != null){
            customerCredit = itemReader.read();
            counter++;
        }
        itemReader.close();
    }
```

I have found that some documents said JdbcCursorItemReader will close the connection automatically after query. However, why do we need itemReader.close() here?
Does JdbcCursorItemReader have to close connection manually?

Comment: You don't and the use of your `JdbcCursorItemReader` is weird. YOou don't read yourself generally you let Spring Batch do that. The close doesn't make sense either. So I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet from reference docs you linked explains how things work behind the scene, but when the reader is used in a chunk-oriented step, you don't need to call `open/close` methods yourself, Spring Batch will do it. So your item reader bean definition should be something like:

```
public ItemReader<RevertedBillCredit> verifyCreditReader() {     
    JdbcCursorItemReader itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader();
    itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemReader.setSql("SELECT ID, NAME, CREDIT from CUSTOMER");
    itemReader.setRowMapper(new CustomerCreditRowMapper());
    return itemReader;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to close connection when using tasklet approach? and for my example, how to pass itemReader to the List ? Or, How can I print out the itemReader to the log because I want to see how JdbcCursorItemReader  work in spring batch.